# ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, importerror

can anyone say what was the problem here ,when i try to import beautifulsoup from bs4.should i change the path ? If it is path error then how it could be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` this is the correct format - uppercase `B` and uppercase `S`